# darknet,Yolov7によるBBOXのデータをcsvで出力したい

Tags: python, 機械学習

## 前提

darknetでYolov7を用いて物体検出AIの作成を行っています。
使用している環境は以下のとおりです。
Ubuntu 22.0.4 LTS
CUDA 11.07
cuDNN 8.5.0
GPU RTX 3600 Ti
Python 3.10.6

AIの作成、検出はうまくいったのですが、検出結果にあるBBOXの座標を取得したく考えています。

お役に立つかわかりませんが、参考までにディープラーニング実行の際には以下のよなコードを端末に打ち込み実行しています。

./darknet detector train cfg/practice.data cfg/practice.cfg yolov7.conv.132

## 実現したいこと

上記の通り、BBOXの値をcsv形式で保存し、その後はOpenCVにより検出された物体の情報を取得したく考えています。

## 発生している問題

これを検討するに当たり、以下の２つのページが参考になるかと思いましたが、自分では実装することが叶いませんでした。
https://teratail.com/questions/349035
https://www.pref.fukushima.lg.jp/uploaded/life/576901_1580201_misc.pdf

試したこと
１つめのサイトを見て試みたこと
・コードをとりあえず端末とPython3で打ち込んでみる→（案の定）失敗。

２つめのサイト（論文）を見て試みたこと
・"image.c"で"draw_detections"を検索し"print"を検索したものの対象が複数個ありどこに以下のコードを挿入すればいいのかわからない。

printf(" -> (x, y, w, h)\n");
printf(" = (%d, %d, %d, %d)\n",
(int)(dets[i].bbox.x*im.w),

(int)(dets[i].bbox.y*im.h),
(int)(dets[i].bbox.w*im.w),

(int)(dets[i].bbox.h*im.h));

## 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

以上の通りとなります。見ての通り知識が不足しており質問においても不十分な点があるかと思います、もし必要な情報がございましたらなんなりとお申し付けください。

お手数ですが、お力添え下さいますと幸いです。何卒よろしくお願いします。

Comment: [他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿](https://teratail.com/questions/gy87k22r2optd2) をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)

Comment: 「コードをとりあえず端末とPython3で打ち込んでみる→（案の定）失敗。」の”失敗”とは具体的には何がどうなったのでしょうか？